# featuretools: can I create a new features by multiplying 2 existing variables and then obtain transform primitives of that feature?

Tags: featuretools

My data contains the variables `Price` and `Quantity`. I'd like to combine them into a new variable containing the total amount of purchase which is the multiple of these 2.

At the back of that, I'd like to obtain the cum_sum of the 3 variables, `Price`, `Quantity` and `Price * Quantity`.

I am setting up the dfs as follows:

```
trans_primitives = ["multiply_numeric","cum_sum"]

feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name="items",
    agg_primitives=[],
    trans_primitives=trans_primitives,
    primitive_options={
        ("multiply_numeric"): {
            'include_columns': {'items': ['Price', 'Quantity']}}},
    verbose=True,    
)
```

But that snippet returns the cum_sum only of Price and Quantity, and not from the product of the 2.

So if I execute `feature_defs` the result is:

```
[<Feature: Invoice>,
 <Feature: Quantity>,
 <Feature: Price>,
 <Feature: CUM_SUM(Price)>,
 <Feature: CUM_SUM(Quantity)>,
 <Feature: Price * Quantity>]
```

and what I want is:

```
[<Feature: Invoice>,
 <Feature: Quantity>,
 <Feature: Price>,
 <Feature: CUM_SUM(Price)>,
 <Feature: CUM_SUM(Quantity)>,
 <Feature: CUM_SUM(Price * Quantity),
 <Feature: Price * Quantity>]
```

Is this possible out of the box?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question.

The call to `ft.dfs` will not automatically generate a `CUM_SUM(price*quantity)` feature because that would mean stacking two `TransformPrimitives` on top of each other, which is not permitted in Featuretools.

Instead, you can use seed features ([documentation available here](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/tuning_dfs.html?highlight=seed%20featuers#Using-%22Seed-Features%22)) to ensure the desired feature is created.

Here is an example of how you could set up the call to `dfs`:

```python
cum_sum_of_price_times_quantity = ft.TransformFeature(ft.TransformFeature([es["items"].ww["price"], es["items"].ww["quantity"], primitive=ft.primitives.MultiplyNumeric), primitive=ft.primitives.CumSum)   
trans_primitives = ["multiply_numeric","cum_sum"]

feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name="items",
    agg_primitives=[],
    trans_primitives=trans_primitives,
    primitive_options={
        ("multiply_numeric"): {
            'include_columns': {'items': ['price', 'quantity']}}},
    seed_features=[cum_sum_of_price_times_quantity], 
    verbose=True,    
)
```